# Get mean from row values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of a set of voltages at different points in time

**edit:** thanks for your help! This df was created from a google sheet file where everything was a string. Today was my first time using pandas, I learned:

- setting axis
- filter
- astype
- select_dtypes & head()_to_dict()

//

```
  Measurements Release 5 Release 6 Release 7
0           V0        48        48        50
1           V1        49        51        53
2           V2        50        52        54
3           V3        51        53        55
```

All voltages are measured at the same point for each new fw release. I want to calculate the mean for each one of these 4 points but can't seem to make it work, though documentation seems simple enough

```
print(df.mean())
Release 5    12123762.75
Release 6    12128813.25
Release 7    12633863.75
dtype: float64
```

Not sure where it gets those numbers. I tried using df.loc to get a row and then get the mean

```
print(df.loc['V1'].mean())


ValueError: No axis named V1 for object type DataFrame
```

And then

```
print(df.iloc[1].mean())
TypeError: Could not convert V1495153 to numeric
```

Comment: You example is not reproducible, please provide a DataFrame as input and explicit the version of pandas that you are using

Comment: hi @mozway I edited the question copying my df from my terminal. As for pandas, it's 1.3.0

Comment: You should rather provide the output of `df.to_dict()`

Comment: why don't you provide the above requested output? ;)

Comment: The main question is why you have numeric columns as string. How do you load your dataframe? The @mozway's request is important. The output of `df.head().to_dict()` gives this information immediately.

Comment: Yep, the output of head_to dict is a dictionary  where values are strings. Out[11]: 
{'Measurements': {0: 'V0', 1: 'V1', 2: 'V2', 3: 'V3'},
 'Release 5': {0: '48', 1: '49', 2: '50', 3: '51'},
 'Release 6': {0: '48', 1: '51', 2: '52', 3: '53'},
 'Release 7': {0: '50', 1: '53', 2: '54', 3: '55'}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

All your columns have the `object` dtype:

```
>>> df.mean()
Release 5    12123762.75
Release 6    12128813.25
Release 7    12633863.75
dtype: float64

>>> df.dtypes
Measurements    object
Release 5       object
Release 6       object
Release 7       object
dtype: object
```

Convert your columns to numeric first

```
df['mean'] = df.filter(like='Release').astype(float).mean(axis=1)
print(df)

# Output
  Measurements  Release 5  Release 6  Release 7       mean
0           V0         48         48         50  48.666667
1           V1         49         51         53  51.000000
2           V2         50         52         54  52.000000
3           V3         51         53         55  53.000000
```

---

**Old answer**

You can also define Measurements column as the index of your dataframe. It makes sense if you have only numeric columns after that:

```
out = df.set_index('Measurements').mean(axis=1)
print(out)

# Output
Measurements
V0    48.666667
V1    51.000000
V2    52.000000
V3    53.000000
dtype: float64
```

Comment: setting the index seems useful for future reference, thanks! But the result of the mean is NaN (I note that in your example it works?)

Comment: @Joolz. I updated my answer. You just need to convert all `Release` columns to numeric before.

Answer (score 3):

For me working well your solution, maybe need `numeric_only=True` parameter:

```
print(df.mean(numeric_only=True))
Release 5    49.5
Release 6    51.0
Release 7    53.0
dtype: float64
```

For last pandas version use [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html):

```
df.select_dtypes('number').mean()
```

If need mean per rows:

```
df.set_index('Measurements').select_dtypes('number').mean(axis=1)
```

EDIT: For converting columns to numeric before `mean` use:

```
 df.drop('Measurements', axis=1).astype('float').mean(axis=1)
```

Or if `float` failed because bad non numeric values:

```
 (df.drop('Measurements', axis=1)
    .apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
    .mean(axis=1)   )
```

Comment: `numeric_only=True` is being deprecated, the syntax should be `df.select_dtypes('number').mean()`

Comment: I want the mean values to come from the rows, i.e. The mean of the four measurements from V1, V2, etc

Comment: @Joolz - Just add to answer.

Comment: @Joolz - `df.set_index('Measurements').select_dtypes('number').mean(axis=1)`

Comment: @jezrael the result: Measurements
V0   NaN
V1   NaN
V2   NaN
V3   NaN

Comment: @Joolz - What return `print (df.set_index('Measurements').select_dtypes('number'))` ?

Comment: Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [0, 1, 2, 3] @jezrael

Comment: @Joolz - Answer was edited with converting to numeric.